# Find answers in given language

Tags: support, answers, languages, search

Sorry for a stupid question, but I read [How do I search?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/searching) and didn’t understand:
How to find answers in a given (programming) language?

Comment: There isn't a specific feature of search to filter by programming language. You just have to enter the name of the language as a string. For a more difficult but possibly more robust solution you could consider [StackExchange Data Exporer](https://data.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @pxeger I tried typing `Curry`, and it’s kind of funny, but it’s not what i want ((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 100% reliable way, but most of the time, it works pretty well to **search for the language's name** in answers:

```
is:a python
```

This approach does generate some false positives, such as when someone says "my answer is a port of someone else's Python answer." Also, when the name of the language is a common word like Curry, answers that use that word tend to show up near the top of the results list, ahead of answers that actually use the language. One trick that can help is to **sort the results by Newest** instead of Relevance: the more "relevant" answers, ironically, tend to be the ones with false positives.

The bigger drawback is that searching the language name doesn't work well for languages with very short names, such as J. In this case, **[StackExchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/new)** is your best hope. I've put together an example query that finds the latest 100 answers in a given language: https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/1736815/recent-answers-in-a-language. The caveat here is that the query is pretty strict about what header formats it matches, so some answers may be excluded, particularly in languages that frequently list command-line flags or libraries in their answer headers. Feel free to tweak it to make it fit your needs better.

Comment: Thank you! `is:a` method looks not good, eg lang  Factor contains keyword `curry` (
But Data Explorer works well, founded ~13 results with relevant Curry answers!

Comment: With Curry in particular, the SEDE query is going to have some problems because people frequently write the specific dialect in the header. Try searching for `Curry (PAKCS)` or `Curry (KiCS2)` and you'll get a lot more results.